# How to name dynamic column in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been learning VBA for a while but there is one issue that I have been facing that I was not able to figure it out until know.

I want to be able to name a column using VBA, so I can use it later it as a reference column (using INDEX function) in other cells/columns.

I know to how to name a column that is fixed. But that is not what I am looking for.

**Example of my issue:**

This month I am naming column `D` as `TotalAmount`. 
The VBA code can be:

```vba
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TotalAmount", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!C4"
```

I will be referring to that column in other cells using the INDEX function.

However, next month I will be adding a new column (let's say previous month sales) just before Column `D`. So the new column that I want to name as `TotalAmount` the next month will be column `E` as opposed to `D`.

I know that the Column naming should not change when adding a new column and Column `E` will automatically become the `TotalAmount` column. However, I cannot rely on it because the excel sheet is accessed by different people and everyone is doing his own calculations.

So I tried this as well (I am sure it is stupid but hey I am still a noob) but it did not work :(

```vba
Sub Macro4()
    Range("D1").Select 
    '(I can select the desired cell each month using the search function)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActiveCell.Column
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TotalAmount", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!Ci"
End sub
```

So I will be very grateful if anyone could help me or guide me on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'i' is a variable so you cannot use that in quotes. In quotes, its just 'i' and has no value. try `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TotalAmount", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!C" & i`
Not sure if this will resolve your problem though

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Worked like a charm! thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get VBA to find the cell for you:

```
Sub SetNamedRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1").Find("TotalAmount")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TotalAmount", RefersToR1C1:=rng
End Sub
```

The code searches `A1:Z1` for the text `"Total Amount"` and sets the named range to that cell

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for the help!
Will this set the name of the current column? Because they might not be a text "TotalAmount" in the sheet. Rather I want the name of the current column set to "TotalAmount"
I tired the script and it is giving me "run-time error "1004" Application-defined or object defined error" :S

Comment: Try this 'ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TotalAmount", RefersToR1C1:=rng.Address'. That should resolve your error. Saying that, I'm not sure I understand what you are looking to do. So you want the name of current column to be set to "TotalAmount"? if so, why are you looking for a cell with "TotalAmount" init?

Comment: Hello!
Yes I want the current column to be named "TotalAmount".I was just trying to explain to CallumDA33 my point. Because I think he misunderstood my point. 
So I just wanted to name the current Column as "TotalAmount". The challenge was that this month the column I want to name "TotalAmount" is column D. But next month, it will be column E.
Now I can identify each month the right column by searching for a text in the header row. Once any cell in the desired column in selected, I want to name that column "TotalAmount".

Comment: The answer provided earlier with the "& i" worked perfectly! I though maybe there is another way as well. It never hurts to learn different methods